# how to make a layout adaptive in dimensions and position

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

i am using `vue3` with `options api`

`stackbiltz` code is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-kasehp?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue,src%2Fcss%2Finput1.css,src%2FApp.vue)

as shown in the below posted images, i have a gui. when the `radio-button` with obliterated label is selected, nothing should happen. however, when the one labeled `Sentinel-Hub` is selected, another `radio-button` should appear as shown in `image-2` posted
below.

But as you see in `image-2`, the section labeled `...comparison Type` remains in the same position no matter if the `radio-button` `Sentinel-2-L1C` appeared or not.
my question is, how to make the layout adaptive in dimensions and position with respect to the display or the appearance of the `radio-button` `Sentinel-2-L1C`?
in other words, what i want to achieve is, when the `radio-button` `Sentinel-2-L1C` appears, the section labeled `....comparison Type` should adapt itself shifting toward the bottom a little.

is that possible to be achieved? how please

**template of `radio-button` `Sentinel-2-L1C`**:

```
<template>
<cds-radio id="idRadioBtnsSenHubMissionSentinel_2_L1CContainer" v-if="isShowRadioBtnsSenHubMissionSentinel_2_L1C">
    <label id="idSenHubMissionSentinel_2_L1CLabel"> {{ tempTextSenHubMissionSentinel_2_L1C }} </label>
    <input
        type="radio"
        :value="compPropsVModelSenHubMissionSentinel_2_L1C"
        @input="$emit('update:compPropsVModelSenHubMissionSentinel_2_L1C', $event.target.value)"
        :disabled="isRadioButtonSenHubMissionSentinel_2_L1Disabled"
        :checked="isCheckedRadioButtonSenHubMissionSentinel_2_L1"
        @change="onSenHubMissionSentinel_2_L1Changed()"
    />
</cds-radio>
```

**CSS of `radio-button` `Sentinel-2-L1C`**:

```
#idRadioBtnsSenHubMissionSentinel_2_L1CContainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 251px;
}
#idSenHubMissionSentinel_2_L1CLabel {
    position:absolute
}
```

**image-1**:

[image]

**image-2**:

[image]